# Algebraic fractions: addition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I have very elementary question about adding algebraic fractions. 
Now, I know the following:

$$\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} = \frac{da + cb}{dc}$$

My question is however, how given this expression:

$$\frac{(2n + 1) \; n(n + 1)}{2} + \frac{(2n + 1) \; n(n + 1)}{6}$$

One arrives at:
$$\frac{(2n + 1) \; n(n + 1)}{3}$$

Trying to work out the solution, I arrive at a very large equation divided by 12...

Comment: Did you ever hear about the *smallest*  common denominator?

Comment: Can you check the answer? It seems to be wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{(2n + 1) n(n + 1)}{2} + \frac{(2n + 1) n(n + 1)}{6}
=
(2n+1)n(n+1) \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} \right)
=
\frac{2(2n+1)n(n+1)}{3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

One should not arrive at that value, as it is not true. Notice that the numerators are the same. This is essentially

$$\frac{(2n+1)n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{(2n+1)n(n+1)}{6} = (2n+1)n(n+1) \left(\frac12 + \frac16\right).$$

Now, it is easy to show that $\frac12+\frac16 = \frac23$, so you should get

$$\frac{2(2n+1)n(n+1)}{3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$
\dfrac{A}{2}+\dfrac{A}{6}=\dfrac{3A+A}{6}=\dfrac{4A}{6}=\dfrac{2A}{3}
$
and your $A$ is ......

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\frac{(2n + 1) \; n(n + 1)}{2} + \frac{(2n + 1) \; n(n + 1)}{6} &= \frac{3(2n + 1) \; n(n + 1)}{6}+\frac{(2n + 1) \; n(n + 1)}{6} \\ 
&= \frac{4(2n + 1) \; n(n + 1)}{6} \\
&= \frac{2(2n + 1) \; n(n + 1)}{3}
\end{align}$$

The equality is obtained by multiplying the first term by $1=\frac{3}{3}$.

The second is obtained by adding the numerators (as the denominators are the same).

The third is by noticing $\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$